# how to include active X in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, activex, dwg

developing an application to open and view dwg files on the android os using eclipse IDE
i found an open source dwg viewer active x

but how to include this activeX in android ??

Answer (score 3):

ActiveX is only available on windows in IE (as far as i know).

Here is what the Firefox people say about it http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/activex .